# Why "OnClickListener" is not working

Tags: android

I can't understand why this simple code is not working.
This code suppose to set the color of the button's text to blue, that's all. 
I only added to a new created project the lines :

```
 final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
             btn.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });
```

The full code :

```
package com.example.b;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click
             btn.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: post `fragment_main.xml`

Comment: Feel free to explain what "not working" means.

Comment: +1 Raghunandan thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the button is in the fragment and not the activity. If so, move your findViewById and your setonclick code into your PlaceHolderFragment.

Comment: Thank you , i moved the button to the main activity and every thing is perfect. thanks again.